# Using Flex and Bison together

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lex

First of all I have to make it clear that I am a beginner regarding flex and bison programming.

I'm trying to write a code recognizing a particular declaration part. Its syntax and logic can be understood by the flex and bison code, I present below:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
[ \t\n]+                { /* Ignore all whitespace */ }
var                     { return VAR; }
real                    { return REAL; }
boolean                 { return BOOLEAN; }
integer                 { return INTEGER; }
char                    { return CHAR; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*   { return VAR_NAME; }
.                       { return yytext[0]; }
%%
program : VAR typedecls ;
typedecls : typedecl | typedecls typedecl ;
typedecl : varlist ':' var_type ';' ;
varlist : VAR_NAME | varlist ',' VAR_NAME ;
var_type : REAL | BOOLEAN | INTEGER | CHAR ;
%%
main( argc, argv )
int argc;
char **argv;
{
++argv, --argc; /* skip over program name */
if ( argc > 0 )
yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
yyin = stdin;
yylex();
}
```

The problem lies to compiling. When compiling on the terminal I get the following lines of errors:

[image]

What is going wrong with my code? How can I fix the errors?

I am looking forward to reading your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misread the instructions for using these tools!

Two different files are required, not one.

A file such as exercise4.l is the input to `flex` which defines the mapping from *lexemes* to *tokens*, and exercise4.y would be the input to `bison` which defines the order of the *tokens* in a *grammar*. To use the two tools together we have to combine the output of `flex` (in this case `lex.yy.c` with the bison grammar using the `#include "lex.yy.x"` directive; the tokens are declared with the `%token` declaration.)

Based on your example, we could re-factor this into two files:

**exercise4.l**:

```
%%
[ \t\n]+                { /* Ignore all whitespace */ }
var                     { return VAR; }
real                    { return REAL; }
boolean                 { return BOOLEAN; }
integer                 { return INTEGER; }
char                    { return CHAR; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*   { return VAR_NAME; }
.                       { return yytext[0]; }
%%
```

**exercise4.y**:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>    
%}
%token VAR VAR_NAME REAL BOOLEAN INTEGER CHAR
%%
program : VAR typedecls ;
typedecls : typedecl | typedecls typedecl ;
typedecl : varlist ':' var_type ';' ;
varlist : VAR_NAME | varlist ',' VAR_NAME ;
var_type : REAL | BOOLEAN | INTEGER | CHAR ;
%%
main( argc, argv )
int argc;
char **argv;
{
extern FILE *yyin;
++argv, --argc; /* skip over program name */
if ( argc > 0 )
yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
yyin = stdin;
/* yylex(); */
yyparse();
}
yyerror(char *s)  
{  
 printf("\nError\n");  
}
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

We can now combine these with the following command lines operations:

```
C:\Users\Brian>flex exercise4.l    
C:\Users\Brian>bison exercise4.y    
C:\Users\Brian>gcc -o exercise4.exe exercise4.tab.c -lfl
```

and test the resultant parser:

```
C:\Users\Brian>.\exercise4
var a:integer;
^Z
```

Comment: Thank you for your very very useful answer. I will check it out!

Comment: Why does the terminal show me exercise4: command not found?( I have faithfully followed your guidelines)

Comment: type `./exercise4` if on linux, or `.\exercise4` if on windows. It is because of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: There is a problem your suggested answer. Starting writing a declaration part without the keyword 'var' at the beginning is allowed. I want every declaration part to begin only with the 'var' keyword. How can it be done?

Comment: @DimitrisBouloutas - I just implemented the grammar as you wrote it with no changes. If you want the grammar to be different you need to change the grammar, which is a different question. You asked how to make you grammar build with flex and bison together, which I showed you - with no changes. It is exactly what you wrote. Start another question and one of the many world class experts can answer it for you. It is not appropriate to add more to this question.

Comment: Yes, I understood that my question was out of topic and I started a new question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501734/flex-and-bison-beginning-with-a-particular-keyword-a-sentence