# Flex and Bison: Beginning a sentence with a specific keyword

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, lex

I am working on a program using Flex and Bison. My task can be done using only Flex(using start conditions etc.), but I have understood that using Bison might make my life easier. My task is to design a program which recognizes a programming language declaration part. Its syntax and logic can be understood through my code below. My problem is that I want my program to recognize as an acceptable declaration part every part of code which begins **only** with the "**var**" keyword! Until now, I have not managed to do that. How can I succeed it?

I present below my .l (flex) and .y (bison) files.

**exercise4.l**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%%
[ \t\n]+                { /* Ignore all whitespaces */ }
";"         { /* Ignore all semicolons */ }
":"         { /* Ignore all colons */ }
var                     { printf("A keyword: %s\n",yytext); return VAR; }
real                    { printf("A variable type: %s\n",yytext); return REAL; }
boolean                 { printf("A variable type: %s\n",yytext); return BOOLEAN; }
integer                 { printf("A variable type: %s\n",yytext); return INTEGER; }
char                    { printf("A variable type: %s\n",yytext); return CHAR; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*   { printf("A variable name: %s\n",yytext); return VAR_NAME; }
.                       { printf("Unrecognized character!\n"); return yytext[0]; }
%%
```

**exercise4.y**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>    
%}
%token VAR VAR_NAME REAL BOOLEAN INTEGER CHAR
%%
program : VAR typedecls ;
typedecls : typedecl | typedecls typedecl ;
typedecl : varlist ':' var_type ';' ;
varlist : VAR_NAME | varlist ',' VAR_NAME ;
var_type : REAL | BOOLEAN | INTEGER | CHAR ;
%%
main( argc, argv )
int argc;
char **argv;
{
extern FILE *yyin;
++argv, --argc; /* skip over program name */
if ( argc > 0 )
yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
yyin = stdin;
//yylex();
yyparse();
}
yyerror(char *s)  
{  
 printf("\nError\n");  
}
#include "lex.yy.c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scanner never returns `:` or `;` tokens (and complains about `,` being unrecognized). But your grammar includes those tokens.

Consequently,

```
typedecl : varlist ':' var_type ';' ;
```

can never match anything. It doesn't see the `:` it is expecting, and the `var_type` is thus unexpected. (And it wouldn't ever match the `;` if it got that far.)

---

I don't know what ancient tutorial you're following, but the pre-ansi prototype for `main` suggests it was composed in the last century (and not in its final years, either). As a rough guide, I slightly updated your files.

Here's exercise4.l; the most important modification is that I removed the handbuilt trace logs, since I intend to use flex's built-in debugging feature. I also added some options to reduce compiler warnings, and enabled line number tracking for use in error messages. I left in the bug.

```
/* File: exercise4.l */
%{
  /* The bison-generated header file includes token declarations */
  #include "exercise4.tab.h"
%}

%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault
%option yylineno

%%
[ \t\n]+                { /* Ignore all whitespaces */ }
";"                     { /* Ignore all semicolons. BUG */ }
":"                     { /* Ignore all colons. BUG */ }
var                     { return VAR; }
real                    { return REAL; }
boolean                 { return BOOLEAN; }
integer                 { return INTEGER; }
char                    { return CHAR; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*   { return VAR_NAME; }
.                       { return yytext[0]; }
```

And here's the parser, with a few fixes (like using the standard C prototype syntax from the 1989 C standard):

```
/* File: exercise4.y */
%{
  /* Used in this file */
  #include <stdio.h>

  /* Forward and external declarations */
  extern int yylineno;
  int yylex();
  void yyerror(const char* msg);
%}

 /* These two options make error messages more informative */    
%define parse.lac full
%error-verbose

%token VAR VAR_NAME REAL BOOLEAN INTEGER CHAR

%%

program   : VAR typedecls
typedecls : typedecl
          | typedecls typedecl
typedecl  : varlist ':' var_type ';'
varlist   : VAR_NAME
          | varlist ',' VAR_NAME ;
var_type  : REAL | BOOLEAN | INTEGER | CHAR ;

%%

/* Welcome to 1990 */
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  extern FILE *yyin;
  if ( argc > 1 )
    yyin = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
  else
    yyin = stdin;
  if (!yyin) {
    /* If you don't check, you'll end up segfaulting when
     * yylex tries to read from NULL. Checking lets us print
     * a hopefully meaningful error message.
     */
    perror("Could not open file for reading");
    return 1;
  }
  return yyparse();
}

/* Now that error messages have some content, it's worthwhile
 * actually using the argument passed to yyerror */
void yyerror(const char* msg) {
  fprintf(stderr, "At line %d: %s\n", yylineno, msg);
}
```

Now, I run the files through flex, bison and gcc, in that order, to produce an executable:

```
# The `-d` option to flex causes it to insert debugging traces. That's
# a lot less effort and a lot more useful than rolling your own trace
# logs.
flex -d -o exercise4.scan.c exercise4.l
# The `-d` option to bison causes it to output a header file, whose name
# is the same as the output file name with `.c` changed to `.h`. That's
# the file which we need to `#include` in the scanner, so that token
# names are available to scanner actions. Bison also has a debugging
# feature, but you need to use `-t` to enable it, plus add a line at
# runtime. For now, we'll leave it out.
bison -d -o exercise4.tab.c exercise4.y
# Now compile and link an executable:
gcc -Wall -g -o exercise4 exercise4.tab.c exercise4.scan.c
```

Normally, the three shell commands would go into a Makefile so that you could just type `make exercise4` to create the executable. But there's nothing really complicated there.

Now, we can try it out. Since I didn't fix the bugs, you'll easily see the problem:

```
var a, b: integer;
--accepting rule at line 14 ("var")
--accepting rule at line 11 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 19 ("a")
--accepting rule at line 20 (",")
--accepting rule at line 11 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 19 ("b")
--accepting rule at line 13 (":")
--accepting rule at line 11 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 17 ("integer")
At line 1: syntax error, unexpected INTEGER, expecting ':' or ','
```

The lines starting `--` are flex's trace. You can see each token as it is recognized. So when a `:` is encountered in the input, the rule at line 13 is executed. That rule is `{ /* Ignore all colons */ }`. And that's what happens.

The error message at the end was printed by `yyerror`. Thanks to the `%errors-verbose` directive, it tells us what it found (`INTEGER`) and what it was expecting.

Hope that all helps some.

Comment: The scanner matches all I want(keywords, variable names, variable types, ignores colons, semicolons, whitespaces etc. just like I want to), but as I said instead of recognizing every part beginning ONLY with the "var" keyword, recognizes every sentence (beginning with or without "var"). The lectical part is completely right, but the syntax is almost right. If recognizes only the sentences I described above then the syntax will be completely right as well.

Comment: @DimitrisBouloutas: You have an odd definition of the word "ignore". Comments are ignored; the grammar works as though they were not present. Whitespace is ignored. But colons and semicolons *must be seen by the grammar* so they cannot be ignored. They have no semantic value, true. But they still need to be passed through. I edited the answer with an example of how to actually see what is going on during the parse, which I hope helps.

Comment: I have not tested your suggestion yet, but I noticed that your scanner threw a syntax error on your example. I want the variable type "integer" to be recognized by the scanner. Why does it say "unexpected INTEGER, expecting ":" or ";"? That is, your sample declaration part of code is totally right according to my task. Nevertheless, the compiler throws this syntax error. Why?

Comment: @dimitris If you actually read what I wrote, it should be clear. You would see that I deliberately left in your bugs in order to show the improved syntax error. And I've tried to explain why ignoring syntactically important tokens cannot work, both in the answer and my previous comment. Delete the lines marked `BUG` and compare behaviour.

Comment: I have a problem while executing. After having written the unix commands you suggested I get "command not found" or  "No such a file or a directory" errors. I tried ./exercise4.out, ./exercise4.exe, exercise4.exe, but nothing worked! What shall I write on terminal to run the program?

Comment: @DimitrisBouloutas: `./exercise4`. That's the actual filename produced when you write `gcc -o exercise4`  :)